# Can you see a logic error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have this script:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 * Template Name: modify.php
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>


    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">


            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>



<?php

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if($user_id==0)
{
    echo "Login please";
    exit;
}

mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die (mysql_error());
#echo "Connected to MYSQL ";
mysql_select_db("derp") or die (mysql_error());
#echo "Connected to Data Base";
/*$query = "SELECT * FROM addserverame WHERE userId='{$user_id}'";
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die (mysql_error());*/

    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM addserverame WHERE ID = $_GET[id] AND userId='{$user_id}'";
    $result = mysql_query ($q);
    $person = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
    }

    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Add Your Server</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">

        <h1><a>Modify Server</a></h1>
        <form id="form_606591" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>Add Your Server</h2>
            <p></p>
        </div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="servername">Server Name </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="Servername" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $person['servername']; ?>"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_1"><small>Enter your server name here NOT your server address.</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="Serveraddress">Server Address </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_2" name="Serveraddress" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $person['serveraddress']; ?>"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_2"><small>This will the DNS name of your server</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="Portnumber">PortNumber </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_3" name="Portnumber" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $person['portnumber']; ?>"/> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_3"><small>This will be the port your server is using.</small></p> 
        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="Description">Server Description </label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="element_4" name="Description" class="element textarea medium" value ="<?php echo $person['description']; ?>"></textarea> 
        </div><p class="guidelines" id="guide_4"><small>Enter server description/rules here.</small></p> 
        </li>

                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Modify" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>-
</html>

<?

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $u = "UPDATE addserverame SET `servername`='$_POST[Servername]', `serveraddress`='$_POST[Serveraddress]', `portnumber`='$_POST[Portnumber]', `description`='$_POST[Description]' WHERE ID = $_POST[id] AND userId='{$user_id}'";
    mysql_query($u) or die (mysql_error());
    echo "Server Info Has Been Modified";
}
?>

    </div><!-- #primary -->
        </div><!-- Content -->

<?php //endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I cant figure what, if any what the logical errors are.

**Whats meant to happen**
the user chooses to update a table if the table is theirs they should be able to edit it and update the table.

**Whats happening** 
the user will try and edit it but it will not update there is no successful modify echo and they are redirected to the front page.

Can any one in all there wisdom explain to me why this is happening instead of what i want to happen.

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Don't paste full code, only the important one. Help us to help you

Comment: Why do you print `<div id="primary" class="site-content">` and then `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...` ?

Comment: @Victor, no point really i believe that html was from a template, its not relevant at this point any way,

Comment: It IS relevant. `get_header()` calls your `header.php` file which already contains the `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...` stuff. I also might add that you're using `mysql_query` which is not safe and almost deprecated while WordPress already provides you with the [`$wpdb` class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: @RRikesh so you cant see any logical errors that will help then.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the probab cause for your form t fail is that the form is not runing in your default page thatts routing to somewhere in your index page as   gives you the php file thats executing and that the index.php so the main cause may be your form action i.e. you are using action in your form like

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
```

so it might be redirecting to your home page i.e. index.php so place your form action blank might this help you

Comment: dude you are my hero, I dont have a medal to give you, but i can give you a thumbs up and correct answer. thanks for your time